# cloudformation says "invalid character"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What is wrong in this code? Everytime I upload a new template while creating cloudformation it says invalid character

```
---
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2
      InstanceType: t2.micro
```

Comment: Is there a specific example/guide you're following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your YAML syntax is correct, You've entered region instead of availability zone. Your code should be something like this. (Changed AvailabilityZone to eu-west-1a)

```
---
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-1a
      ImageId: ami-a4c7edb2
      InstanceType: t2.micro
```

Try that, should work